# NSSet and Core Data

Tags: swift

I am trying to save two lists of objects in core data. I have a protocol method which adds my tags as (Tag) and puts them into an array of tags. I am not able to save these objects as I am using an NSSet and the extension (for swift) as:

```
extension CurrentTransaction {
func addTagObject(value:Tag) {
    var items = self.mutableSetValueForKey("tagMembers");
    items.addObject(value)
 }

 func removeTagObject(value:Tag) {
    var items = self.mutableSetValueForKey("tagMembers");
    items.removeObject(value)
 }
}
```

The two objects from core data I am trying to save are:

```
class Pic: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var picName: String!
@NSManaged var picNumber: String!
@NSManaged var currentTransaction: CurrentTransaction

class func createInManagedObjectContext(moc: NSManagedObjectContext, name: String, number: String) -> Pic {
    let newPic = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Pic", inManagedObjectContext: moc) as! Pic
    newPic.picName = name
    newPic.picNumber = number

    return newPic
}
}
```

class Tag:

```
class Tag: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var tagName: String!
@NSManaged var tagNumber: String!
@NSManaged var currentTransaction: CurrentTransaction

class func createInManagedObjectContext(moc: NSManagedObjectContext, name: String, number: String) -> Tag {
    let newTag = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Tag", inManagedObjectContext: moc) as! Tag
    newTag.tagName = name
    newTag.tagNumber = number

    return newTag
}


}
```

class currentTransaction:

```
class CurrentTransaction: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var destinationPIC: String
@NSManaged var sourcePIC: String
@NSManaged var nvdNumber: String
@NSManaged var numberOfAnimals: NSNumber
@NSManaged var requestType: String
@NSManaged var date: NSDate
@NSManaged var tagMembers: NSSet
@NSManaged var picMembers: NSSet?


class func createInManagedObjectContext(moc: NSManagedObjectContext, toPic: String, fromPic: String, nvd: String, numAnimals: NSNumber, request: String, date: NSDate, tags: NSSet, pics: NSSet) -> CurrentTransaction {

    let newTransaction = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("CurrentTransaction", inManagedObjectContext: moc) as! CurrentTransaction

    newTransaction.destinationPIC = toPic
    newTransaction.sourcePIC = fromPic
    newTransaction.nvdNumber = nvd
    newTransaction.numberOfAnimals = numAnimals
    newTransaction.requestType = request
    newTransaction.tagMembers = tags
    newTransaction.picMembers = pics
    newTransaction.date = date

    return newTransaction
}

}
```

When I call the CurrentTransaction.addTagObject(tag:Tag) I get "Cannot invoke 'addTagObject' with an argument list of type '(Tag)'

Here is my addTags protocol method:

```
func addTags(tag: Tag) {
    //println("IN ADD TAGS")
    //println(tag.tagNumber)
    self.tagList.append(tag)
    CurrentTransaction.addTagObject(tag) //Error on this line
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason: addTagObject() is not defined as class function and cannot be invoked on class CurrentTransaction. If you intended to use it as class fucntion, change it to:

```
class func addTagObject(value:Tag) {
    var items = self.mutableSetValueForKey("tagMembers");
    items.addObject(value)
}
```

Comment: I am now getting "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key tagMembers." ! Any ideas what I am doing wrong?